# Matching patterns in spaCy returns a empty result

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, pos-tagger

I was hoping to find some patterns with this simple code. But the result is empty.
I'm forgetting something?

```
for tk in doc[:30]:
     print (tk.text, ':', tk.pos_)
```

Método : NOUN
de : ADP
avaliaçãoSimulação : NOUN
computacional : ADJ
conforme : ADP
procedimentos : NOUN
apresentados : VERB
em : ADP
: SPACE
Ediﬁ : PROPN
cações : NOUN
em : ADP
fase : NOUN
de : ADP
projetoA : NOUN
avaliação : NOUN
deve : VERB
ser : AUX
feita : VERB
para : ADP
um : NUM
dia : NOUN
típico : ADJ
de : ADP
projeto : NOUN
de : ADP
verão : NOUN
e : CCONJ
de : ADP

```
pattern = [
       {'POS': 'NOUN'},
       {'LOWER': 'ADP'},
       ]
```

```
    #Matcher class object
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
matcher.add("matching_1", patterns = [pattern]) 

result = matcher(doc, as_spans=True) 

print(result)
```

[]

So I was expecting the pattern of the POS Tags 'NOUN' + 'ADP' could find the words:
'Método de',
'cações em',
'fase de',
'projeto de'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following rule will match a token that equals "ADP" when made lowercase. This will not match anything because "ADP" is not lowercase.

```
{'LOWER': 'ADP'},
```

I am not sure what this is supposed to match, maybe you want to match a lowercase word with POS = ADP? In that case you would want a rule like this:

```
{"POS": "ADP", "REGEX": "^[a-z]+$"}
```

---

To restate what I said above: `{'LOWER': 'ADP'}` **does not** match a lowercase word with the ADP part of speech. You seem to be confused about what "LOWER" means or how rules work.

Let me give an example. `{"LOWER": "dog"}` will match words like "Dog", "DOG", or "dog". It will not match words with the part of speech "dog" (which do not exist). `"LOWER": value` means, "match words which look like `value` when they are made lowercase".

If you want to match lower case words that have the ADP part of speech, you should use the rule I wrote above with the `REGEX` bit.

Comment: 'POS' looks for the term 'NOUN' in the labels that have been given to each word. 'LOWER' will similarly search for the label 'ADP' in lowercase words only. This is the default structure of a matcher method within SpaCy.
But, as you can see from the edit to the question I just made, this pattern should find some sets of words, which have the labels in this sequence (NOUN + ADP), but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I edited my answer to be clearer. The pattern you wrote does not work in the way you describe.

Comment: Tks Sr! Sorry for the misunderstanding!